# How can I use Django Social Auth to connect with Twitter?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-socialauth

I'm trying to use the [Django Social Auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) package to connect with Twitter, but I'm having difficulty understanding how exactly to do this as I can't find any examples. I am assuming that `Django Social Auth` is the best package to use for this purpose.

I've looked at a few examples that use Facebook, and from this have added the following to my `settings.py` file:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_auth.backends.twitter.TwitterBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

# overwriting default templates
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (    
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_type_backends',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_ENABLED_BACKENDS = ('twitter')
SOCIAL_AUTH_DEFAULT_USERNAME = 'new_social_auth_user'

# Social media login info:
TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY         = 'xxx'
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET      = 'xxxxxx'

# 'magic' settings
SOCIAL_AUTH_COMPLETE_URL_NAME = 'socialauth_complete'
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATE_URL_NAME = 'associate_complete'

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.social_auth_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.associate.associate_by_email',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.misc.save_status_to_session',
    'social.pipeline.redirect_to_form',
    'social.pipeline.username',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.associate_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.load_extra_data',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.update_user_details',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.misc.save_status_to_session',
    'social.pipeline.redirect_to_form2',
    'social.pipeline.first_name',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_FORCE_POST_DISCONNECT = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_SESSION_EXPIRATION = False
```

In `urls.py` I've added the following lines:

```
url('', include('social_auth.urls')),
url(r'^twitter/', twitter_app, name='twitter_app')
```

And in a file called `twitter.py` I've added the following to create a view:

```
from django.contrib.auth import BACKEND_SESSION_KEY
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect #dq
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template.context import RequestContext

from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.core.cache import cache

from social_auth.models import UserSocialAuth
from social_auth.views import complete as social_complete
from social_auth.utils import setting
from social_auth.backends.twitter import TwitterBackend


# twitter login    
def twitter_app(request):
    """twitter login"""
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('done')
    else:
        return render_to_response('twitter.html', {'twitter_app_id':setting('TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY'),
                                                'warning': request.method == 'GET'}, RequestContext(request))
```

I've then created a template file called `twitter.html` with the following structure:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block script %}

Login with <a href="{% url socialauth_begin 'twitter' %}">Twitter</a>

{% endblock %}
```

This results in the following error message:

> The webpage at http://example.com/twitter/done has resulted in too
>   many redirects.

I'm a little bit lost as to what I should be doing overall. I have created an app on twitter with my site url to generate the api/secret key. Any advice on what direction I should go, or links to working examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The URL to start the twitter authentication should be `{% url socialauth_begin "twitter" %}`, not `'twitter_app'`. That name represents the backend you intend to use. Also you should include DSA `urls.py` into your main urls with a rule like this: `('', include('social_auth.urls'))`. This setting `SOCIAL_AUTH_ENABLED_BACKENDS` doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Thanks @omab I've made these changes, and when I click on `mysite.com/twitter` it just takes me to a page as if I am logged in (even though I did not have to do anything).

Comment: try to create /twitter/done/ page

Comment: I read the documentation now and there is no stated that you must create twitter url or view. You just is to put url twitter in your template

Comment: post your full urls.py, hence if the order you've posted is like the one you're using the latter will never be reached as everything matches the first rule (`url('', include('social_auth.urls')),`) for starters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will give you a sample and this is a customize twitter login,

1. the name of the app is **social**
2. pip install Twython
3. create LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL, TWITTER_SECRET and TWITTER_KEY

**settings.py**

```
# Twitter settings
TWITTER_KEY = 'xxxxxx'
TWITTER_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxx'
```

**models.py**

```
class TwitterProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    oauth_token = models.CharField(
        max_length=200
        )
    oauth_secret = models.CharField(
        max_length=200
        )
    screen_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, 
        blank=True, null=True
        )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.user)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('social.views',      
    url(
        r'^twitter/login/$', 
        "twitter_login", 
        name="twitter_login"
    ),

    url(r'^twitter/callback/$', 
        "twitter_callback", 
        name="twitter_callback"
    ),   
)
```

**views.py**

```
def twitter_login(request):
    twitter = Twython(
        twitter_token = settings.TWITTER_KEY,
        twitter_secret = settings.TWITTER_SECRET,
        callback_url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('social:twitter_callback'))
    )
    auth_props = twitter.get_authentication_tokens()
    request.session['request_token'] = auth_props
    return HttpResponseRedirect(auth_props['auth_url'])


def twitter_callback(request, redirect_url=settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL):
    twitter = Twython(
        twitter_token = settings.TWITTER_KEY,
        twitter_secret = settings.TWITTER_SECRET,
        oauth_token = request.session['request_token']['oauth_token'],
        oauth_token_secret = request.session['request_token']['oauth_token_secret'],
    )

    authorized_tokens = twitter.get_authorized_tokens()

    try:
        profile = TwitterProfile.objects.get(screen_name = authorized_tokens['screen_name'])
        user = User.objects.get(pk=profile.user_id)
        user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'

        if user.is_active:
            auth_login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app_name:url_name'))
        else:
            //failed back to login
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app_name:login'))
    except TwitterProfile.DoesNotExist:
        screen_name = authorized_tokens['screen_name']
        oauth_token = authorized_tokens['oauth_token']
        oauth_token_secret = authorized_tokens['oauth_token_secret']

        //create new twitter profile
        //create new user here
        //authenticate the new register user then login
        .........
```

**template**

```
<a href="{% url social:twitter_login %}">Twitter</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Do you know if the `views.py` aspect would be similar with `django-socialauth`?

Comment: yeah that's the origin but I customize it a little because it difficult to follow and use third party app

Comment: ok - I'll test it out. Were these the only changes to `settings.py`the twitter keys? Also what did you add to `urls.py`?

Comment: twitter keys and secret. I forgot the urls.py codes sorry. I will update it right away